# Confirmed Shipping Address

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I have integrated mobile PayPal payments as explained here: https://devblog.paypal.com/phonegap-android-sdk-plugin/

My question is not about programming, because it works well.
Someone from my backoffice told me to verify that our payments are shipped to a confirmed shipping address given by the PayPal API.
Now, what I did was to allow PayPal payments trough logging into your account or simply by inserting your credit card's number then verify those payments (following this section: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/).

What I think is that my colleague is referring to the Mobile Express Checkout that we didn't use. (I read that using this you have to verify the shipping informations)

Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confirmed address simply means the address you're shipping to matches the billing address of a credit card the person has on file with PayPal.  This greatly reduces the chance that it could be a fraudulent order.

When you receive the payment you can look at your API response.  Depending on which calls you're making it may have the address_status included in the response for you.

If not, you could setup an IPN listener to receive transaction data and that would include the address_status.  It would also include a protection_eligibility parameter to let you know whether or not the transaction was covered by PayPal Seller Protection.

The address status is also available in the PayPal transaction details so you could easily see it there any time you're reviewing orders or printing labels through PayPal.

Finally, you could setup Fraud Management Filters in your PayPal profile so that payments without a confirmed address are automatically denied.

If you're using Payments Pro to process cards directly you can look at the AVS response that's included with the API response.  It will provide a letter that resembles whether or not the full address matches, just the street address, just the zip code, or no match at all.

Comment: Andrew, thnaks for your response.
Let me telling you another thing. In our app, we request to the user bot a shipping and billing address, then we accept his payment trough PayPal (by using the plugin) and eventually ship to the shipping address inserted by the user. Is this case exposed to fraud?

Comment: It is if you're not verifying the address that you're shipping to one way or another, yes.  Are you checking the PayPal address_status prior to shipping products?

Comment: The project it's not already started so we didn't have any orders now, but just to summarize: there is no need to implement an address confirmation through Mobile COrdova Plugin, we can just receive payments then we access our Account, see the transactions and decide to ship only to the ones with a confirmed shipping address and issue a refund (or contact the customers) of the ones without it?
Thank you

Comment: Yes, that would work fine.  What I would recommend is on orders where the shipping address isn't confirmed give those people a call and feel them out over the phone.  Then make a conscience decision on whether or not to ship that particular order.  Some people do have legitimate reasons for shipping to addresses that aren't their credit card billing address, so it's all a matter of how much risk you're willing to take on a per order basis.